# Why are there so many low-stack, hyper turbo, infinite rebuy/addon tournaments?

Tags: poker-history

I refuse to believe that these sorts of tournaments are anything else but a gamble. You just cannot do well in them consistently, even the best tournament players in the world will probably go bust from an all-in or whither away due to the low-stack and rising blinds.

***So why are there so freaking many of them?***

Comment: I would assume supply and demand - if they're getting runners, the sites will continue to increase the volume available to accommodate the players who want to play them...

Comment: Sites do not add tournaments for your benefit. They do it for their benefit.

Comment: There are many players who successfully grind micro stakes tournaments, you're likely playing them wrong and don't understand NASH charts

Answer (score 1):

Micro stakes tournaments are certainly profitable. It takes a very different play style. xflixx (Felix Schneiders) has some great ebooks on this play style.

But to answer your question, there are two main reasons. Firstly, the quantity of players who play these stakes make it worthwhile to host these tournaments. Both recreational players and just straight grinders enjoy them.

Secondly, To get people's foot in the door. People will easily tell themselves "I will just play the cheap tourneys" until either:

1. The gambler's mindset kicks in
2. They get bored of the cheap tournaments or
3. are just otherwise tempted to move up.

Micro tournaments are a non-threatening way to attract *more players* into buy-ins.

Comment: Agreed.  And since new/recreational players are attracted to these (more action and don't take several hours of their time), that is exactly why they can be profitable to pros.  More bad players = more dead money.